# How do I achieve a WordPress theme demo like Uncode?

Tags: php, wordpress

Uncode WordPress theme demo: https://undsgn.com/uncode/

What I want to know how to achieve, specifically, is how to show off the different theme header types in a single WordPress installation the way the developers of Uncode theme have done.

The demo for Uncode is a single WordPress installation. The theme options are powered by the Redux framework: https://reduxframework.com/

There is a single setting within the theme options to select a header type. These are seen here: https://undsgn.com/uncode/features/menu-variations/

Now, in the live demo, what I would expect to see is that whichever header type is selected in the theme options, that header will be set for all the pages and posts that you navigate through in the demo.

However, when you browse through the different pages under the "Home" menu item, the header type dynamically changes to suit that page.. and the interesting part for me - when you then navigate through other pages and posts like those under the "Pages", "Works" and "Blog" menu items, the last header type that you saw remains selected for all of these other pages/posts.

This allows you to see the same page or post using all of the different header/menu types depending on which one you last saw from the "Home" pages.

If this is a single WordPress installation, and the header type option is a single setting in the Redux framework options - how is it possible to show the different header options across all of the "Home" pages?

Comment: use different templates for each page header